# how to remove items from langchain memory

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

inside the langchain memory object there are different methods e.g. `ConversationBufferMemory` or `ConversationBufferWindowMemory`

Regardless, if the conversation get long at somepoint I get the following error

```
openai.error.InvalidRequestError: This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens. However, your messages resulted in 4113 tokens (4063 in the messages, 50 in the functions). Please reduce the length of the messages or functions.
```

because the context get full. I wonder how I can remove the last object or apply some moving window strategy ?

Answer (score 3):

```
def ClearMemory():

    conversation.memory.clear()
```

That's it! Call this function whenever you want to clear memory.

Comment: Thanks - but I don't intent to erase the entire memory, rather would like to remove "items" from it :-)

Answer (score 0):

If `memory` is an instance of `ConversationBufferMemory`, for example, you can access past messages with `memory.chat_memory.messages`.

The method `memory.clean()` sets `memory.chat_memory.messages` to an empty list, so it deletes all memory. See [here](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/92c34d48036272f0f47e591e3319b2ac87e45e34/libs/langchain/langchain/memory/chat_memory.py#L54) and [here](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/92c34d48036272f0f47e591e3319b2ac87e45e34/libs/community/langchain_community/chat_message_histories/in_memory.py#L28) for the respective code parts. What you can do is

```
memory.chat_memory.messages = memory.chat_memory.messages[:-2]
```

to, for example, delete the last two messages.

To overwrite them, you could then use

```
memory.save_context({"input": "Servus"}, {"output": "Grüezi!"})
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure if you can remove the objects but the [ConversationBufferWindowMemory](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/types/buffer_window) with `k=2` or `k=3` should've done the trick.

If you're using RAG maybe the the context gets full with just 2-3 history messages. In that case probably this [page](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/adding_memory_chain_multiple_inputs) makes sense.